# Windows 7 Last Logon Never

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

I have Windows 7 installed and I type `net user [username]` in a command prompt.  I get back all the expected information except 'Last Logon' is set to 'Never'.  I've logged on and off plenty of times.

Why does it show up as 'Never'?

Comment: @paradroid
I'm seeing a last logon date although I'm not on a domain (W7SP1). (this should really be a comment...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a date and time for `Last Logon`.  My guess is that the information is only valid when the computer is on a domain.  This would have to be confirmed by other people having `Never` while they are not on a domain.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance that you've never actually set a password on the account and have always logged in without a password, thus never really seeing the login screen itself?

For example, when I type `net user [username]`, the last logon is when I woke up my computer up from sleep and typed in a password to get into my account again.

Comment: No, the account has a password and I'm always logging in with it.